# How can I prevent the user's voice input for Twilio while the system is saying something?

Tags: twilio

How can I prevent the user's voice input for Twilio while the system is saying something?
I have a `<Say> Some long text</Say>` after which there should be a voice input from the user. However, when the user speaks while the system is reading the long text the reading is being interrupted. I need the user to listen to the text till the end and only then be ready for voice input.

Is it possible to do in Twilio?

Here is the response in XML I'm sending back:

```
`<Response>
  <Gather input="speech" action="MyControllername/MyMethodName" speechTimeout="auto">
    <Say>Here is my very long confidential text</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>/MyControllername/IncorrectOrNoInputMethod</Redirect>
</Response>
`
```

And here is the code:

```
`public async Task<TwiMLResult> MyMethodName()
        {
            var response = new VoiceResponse();
            var message = await _logic.GetMyLongText(); // This test I get from BL, it is an async method
            var gather = new Gather(new [] {Gather.InputEnum.Speech}.ToList(), Url.ActionUri(nameof(AnotherMethodName), ControllerName), speechTimeout: "auto");
            gather.Append(new Say(message));
            response.Append(gather);
            response.Redirect(Url.ActionUri(nameof(IncorrectOrNoInputMethod), ControllerName));
            return TwilioResultFrom(response);
}`
```

Comment: Can you share the TwiML you are generating?

Comment: I've updated the post to contains your request.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

You need to have the Say verb come before the Gather:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Here is my very long confidential text</Say>
  <Gather input="speech" action="MyControllername/MyMethodName" speechTimeout="auto">
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>/MyControllername/IncorrectOrNoInputMethod</Redirect>
</Response>
```

So in you C#, you just call the `Say` method directly on the `response` object verse appending it to `gather`:

```
public async Task<TwiMLResult> MyMethodName()
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse();
    var message = await _logic.GetMyLongText(); // This test I get from BL, it is an async method
    response.Say(message);
    var gather = new Gather(new [] {Gather.InputEnum.Speech}.ToList(), Url.ActionUri(nameof(AnotherMethodName), ControllerName), speechTimeout: "auto");
    response.Append(gather);
    response.Redirect(Url.ActionUri(nameof(IncorrectOrNoInputMethod), ControllerName));
    return TwilioResultFrom(response);
}
```

Hope that helps.